# How to add Impulse noises in image by MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have few confusion and question about adding impulse noise in images using Matlab. I read that the impulse in image categorized in two:
a) salt and pepper (  corruption have graylevel pixel equal to 0 or 255)
b) random valued impulse noise ( where the corrupted pixel can have any value between 0 to 255).
Note: I am talking about grayscale image only.

Till now, I added salt and pepper noise in image with different noise density using Matlab, using the following command:

```
imnoise(image, 'salt & pepper',0.5)
```

So I have a question:
1) how can i add random valued impulse noise in gray scale image with Matlab software?

2) Can a gray scale image corrupted by both noises simultaneously ? If yes, then how with Matlab software?

Thank You.

Comment: check this file from fileexchange: http://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22141-impulse-noise-addition/content/impulsenoise.m

Comment: @leonardo Can you please explain imshow([I Ir]). I googled about it and found a explanation that imshow([I Ir]) displays the image I with associated 2-D spatial referencing object Ir. what does 2-D spatial referencing object Ir meaning ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work if I got your question correctly

```
I = im2double(rgb2gray(imread('peppers.png')));
p = 0.2; % p between 0 and 1
Ir = (I + p*rand(size(I)))/(1+p);
imshow([I Ir])
```

Comment: Please avoid using JS snippets, while the matlab code cannot be executed here.

Comment: @leonardo    can You please explain the following line in detail                  Ir = (I + p*rand(size(I)))/(1+p);  what is rand? and how this statment add random valued impulse noise in image I ? ok got little .. it will create matrix of random numbers. but why it multiply by p and there is (1+p) term?   Thanks

Comment: @user36036 rand returns a single uniformly distributed random number in the interval (0,1). check this out for more: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html

Comment: Thank you. Do have any pixel which have value either 0 or 255? i.e do random valued noise can inherent salt & pepper noise too?

Comment: @user36036 with pixels no idea unfortunately, but the link NKN commented on your question seems to be just the thing you are looking for, take a look, test it.

Comment: ohh that link was skipped by my eyes .. well thanks .. One last thing, I want to know that we are adding those noises by the help of software, I want to know , Can we get any image which is corrupted by impulse noise only or with other noise by the real processing. Thank You.